# Добавление параметров к onclick атрибуту в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть картинка, у неё аттрибут `onclick="todo();"` 
Так вот, возможно ли при помощи jquery добавить к onclick аттрибуту определенные параметры, но сделать это не так - `$(div).attr(onclick, div.attr(onclick)+todo)` а примерно так: `$(div).attr(onclick, .= todo)`  то есть как в пхп, прибавить к текущему значению?

Comment: [mcve] где? а то ерунда какая-то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да  вы можете  примерно так сделать только переназначив onliсk полностю
к примеру

```
var param = 'test';
$(div).attr('onclick','todo("'+param1+'")');
```

если же пхп то примерно так  php часть прошу проверить давно не писал нечего на php

```
<?php 
$param = 'test'
?>
$(div).attr('onclick','todo("<?php echo $param ?>")');
```